# Find object in array with closest date to current time

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdate

I have an array of objects, each with an `NSDate` property called "date".

How can I find the object with the closest date to current time?

Comment: Find the one with the smallest absolute value for `[myObject.date timeIntervalSinceNow]`.

Answer (score 4):

This will leave closestObject with the object that has the closest date. If you don't want past dates, then get rid of the ABS and make sure interval is positive.

```
    MyObjectType *closestObject;
    NSTimeInterval closestInterval = DBL_MAX;

    for (MyObjectType *myObject in array) {
        NSTimeInterval interval = ABS([myObject.date timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]]);
        if (interval < closestInterval) {
            closestInterval = interval;
            closestObject = myObject;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSDate *)closestDateFromArray:(NSArray *)dateArray
{
    double smallestDifference = DBL_MAX; // thanks bgfriend0
    NSDate *closestDate = nil;

    for (NSDate *date in dateArray) {
        // suggested by Henri Normak
        if ([date timeIntervalSinceNow] <= someThresholdValue) {
            return date;
            // you could set some value that is a "good enough" value.
            // i.e. if the date IS NOW then nothing is going to be closer.
        }

        if (ABS([date timeIntervalSinceNow]) < smallestDifference) {
            smallestDifference = ABS([date timeIntervalSinceNow]);
            closestDate = date;
        }
    }

    return closestDate;
}
```

Something like this should do the trick.

If the array is an array of objects that have a date property then you can do exactly the same just get the date out of the object to compare.

Comment: Better way of getting high double would be to use DBL_MAX in <float.h> imo

Comment: Ah, thanks :D Thought that might exist but wasn't sure.

Comment: It might also be worth to add a special condition that stops if the difference gets very small, i.e no need to continue if the difference is 0 for example. This of course is assuming it doesn't matter which of the objects is chosen if they are all with the same date. With 240 objects it might not make that big of a difference, but it seems like a worthy optimisation.

Comment: Also a good point :D will add :D

Comment: Some reason for down vote?

Comment: Gotta love Stack Overflow... lol